# I want an Excel Formula which can Extract Specific Word If total Character 10

Tags: excel

I want to extract some contact numbers inside a cell between some other numbers.
Wanted formula like this "If 463 Available and If Seven Characters on Right Side of 463 Available then Call 463 and Add Zero Before it and Add its Seven Characters at end.

If 463 Not Available then show Not Available

If Seven Characters Not Available after 463 then show Not Completed

Data

```
3498114632030377348901

9856979165879564897347

8978945618978946341897
```

Results

```
04632030377

Not Available

Not Completed
```

Please let me know the formula if it is possible.

Comment: What have you tried so far. Try using functions like search() and left() and right()

Comment: Something like `=IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("463", A1))), IF(LEN(A1)-FIND("463", A1) < 10, "Not Complete", "0" & MID(A1,FIND("463", A1), 10)), "Not available")` should do the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(IF(LEN(A1)-FIND("463",A1)>=9,0&MID(A1,FIND("463",A1),10),"NOT COMPLETED"),"NOT AVAILABLE")
```

[image]

Edit: found a shorter version.

Comment: Its working but it is now showing Not Completed if 463 showing at end before 7 or 8 characters like 342342342346398458748 or 34234234234639845874.

Comment: Still showing Not Completed if after 463 7 or 8 characters.

Comment: @IftekHar I need to go back to basic math.  See edit.

Comment: Yes it is what I want. Thanks

Comment: Please let me know if I want to target 2nd 463 if there is two 463 in a cell like 346342342346398458748

Comment: @IftekHar that is a new question and deserves a new post.

Comment: I have created new question please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51676402/excel-formula-which-can-extract-specific-word-if-repeat

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(463,A1)), IF(FIND(463,A1) + 9 > LEN(A1), "Incomplete", CONCATENATE("0463", MID(A1,FIND(463,A1)+3,7))), "Not Available")
```

Comment: All is fine just showing #VALUE! except Not Available.

Comment: if the value is not found in the string `FIND` will return an error and as such if `463` is not found it will cause the whole formula to error.

Comment: Ah, I see. Note Scott's use of `ISNUMBER(FIND(...))`. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

As an UDF using Regex (I know you wanted a formula but you have excellent answers already)

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim arr(), i As Long
    arr = Array("3498114632030377348901", "9856979165879564897347", "8978945618978946341897")

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Debug.Print ResponseFromCheck(arr(i))
    Next i
End Sub
Public Function ResponseFromCheck(ByVal inputString As String) As String
    Dim re As Object, i As Long
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Dim patterns(): patterns = Array("463", "463\d{7}")
    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        For i = LBound(patterns) To UBound(patterns)
            .pattern = patterns(i)
            If Not .test(inputString) Then
                Select Case i
                Case 0
                    ResponseFromCheck = "Not available"
                Case 1
                    ResponseFromCheck = "Not completed"
                End Select
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
        ResponseFromCheck = "0" & .Execute(inputString)(0)
End With
End Function
```

---

**UDF used in sheet:**

[image: Response]